# static-content not appearing on generated PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, xsl-fo, aspose

The title says it all. I am trying to generate PDF using ASPOSE. 
My XML file looks like this.

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="lead-page">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="3in" margin-right="0.5in" margin-bottom="0.7in" margin-left="0.5in" />
      <fo:region-before extent="4in" region-name="header-first" />
      <fo:region-after extent="0.5in" />
      <fo:region-start extent="0.5in" />
      <fo:region-end extent="1.25in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>

    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="content-pages">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="0.5in" margin-right="0.5in" margin-bottom="1in" margin-left="0.5in" />
      <fo:region-before extent="0.5in" />
      <fo:region-after extent="0.5in" />
      <fo:region-start extent="0.5in" />
      <fo:region-end extent="0.5in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>

    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="page-sequence-master">
      <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="lead-page" />
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="content-pages" />
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page-sequence-master">  
    <fo:static-content flow-name="header-first" margin-right="0.5in" margin-left="0.5in" margin-top="0in">
      <!-- Some static stuff here to display on first page only. -->
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" space-before="0.1in">
      <fo:block>
        <!-- Rest of the stuff -->
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>

  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

There is some static content (Company name, Logo etc.) I am trying to display on just the first page. Everything under `<fo:static-content>` is not getting displayed. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but that worked for me with AH Formatter (after I put an `fo:block` with some content inside the `fo:static-content`).  [Note also that the margins on `fo:static-content` and the `space-before` on `fo:flow` aren't allowed in XSL 1.1.]

Comment: I do not know Aspose (for XSL FO) but there website lists this as only partially supported: Repeatable page master reference

Perhaps that is your issue because what you have works with RenderX, AH Formatter and FOP.

Comment: I stuck <fo:block>Header</fo:block> inside the <static-content> and ran it through Apache FOP and it does display. It's right at the edge of the page, though, probably in your margin.